# PHP code getting commented out in long-tag syntax, .php file

Tags: php, apache, comments

I have looked at the 9398420 other questions about PHP code appearing as comments. The answers all involved either changing file extension (done), changing from `<? ?>` tags to `<?php ?>` tags (done), or using a real web server rather than `file://` (done, and I even made sure to uncomment the PHP5 import statement in `httpd.conf`). What on earth is going on? Here is the code:

```
<!-- DOCTYPE HTML -->
<?php
$uri .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<body>
<?php
echo $uri;
?>
</body>
```

And here is what my browser says the code is:

```
<!-- DOCTYPE HTML -->
<!--?php
$uri .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?-->
<body>
<!--?php
echo $uri;
?-->
</body>
```

Comment: Please open up your network inspector, inspect the page request, and then check the `x-powered-by` in the response header section. Does it include PHP/

Comment: What are you using for a server?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy There doesn't appear to be an `x-powered-by` in the response header.

Comment: @MattinWashington I'm using my Mac's builtin Apache server

Comment: @user2828975 the only things I can think of trying - Restart apache and see if that fixes. If not go through setting up php again to make sure you haven't missed anything

Comment: Done both. I restarted apache and followed the PHP setup from the website itself. It still does the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

When Firefox encounters `<?php ... ?>`, FF thinks it as `<!--?php ... ?-->` (probably because it is an unknown tag.)

in this case, the server is actually sending `<?php ... ?>` to the web browser (which is not much meaningful as PHP is usually used server-side)

**EDIT**

Comment out this:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

**and** `Include /etc/apache2/other/php5.conf` (or similar)

Comment: I know. As I said, I have read the other documentation around and know about that, my problem is that I can't figure out why my server is sending the php in the first place

Comment: @user2828975 `$ httpd -M` should print php5 or php7. Otherwise, mod_php is not available.